# add Country field in registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, register

In my registration form I need to add the Country field.
I would like to use the built-in countries dropdown of Magento. Via backend it is not possible to add it. How should I add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search in this site or google how to add customer attribute. The specific for you case is that your attribute should be with:

```
'type'   => 'varchar',
'input'  => 'select',
'source' => 'customer/entity_address_attribute_source_country',
```

Comment: that source returns only the allowed countries, I would like to have the entire collection of countries. Which source should I use?

Comment: Please try with `catalog/product_attribute_source_countryofmanufacture` or make your own copy of `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Address_Attribute_Source_Country` and in `public function getAllOptions()` remove `->loadByStore($this->getAttribute()->getStoreId())` or replace it with `loadData()`.